# remote login debugging triggered Roaming::RoamingCacheException loading ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, remote-desktop, group-policy

I'm debuggin on started Visual Studio 2017 after remotely logged into the server (Windows 2012 R2, 64-bit) via RDP. Note: so this is a "local debugging after remote login" issue, not a "remote debugging" issue.

Normal C++ project debugging is fine. But I'm working on an Excel plugin, so set the project's property at debugging > command = ...excel.exe. By right, after I started VS debugging, VS shall trigger excel instead, then, if excel loads the project as a plugin and make calls to it, VS can trap the break points.

However, this is now not working: Excel started then exited, before any of my c++ code is called. VS output says there’s an Roaming::RoamingCacheException error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAB71968D8 in EXCEL.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: Roaming::RoamingCacheException at memory location 0x000000D00613A3E0.

If I start excel first, then attach VS to the process by in vs menu debug > attach to process, then VS can successfully hook to excel -- this is now my work-around -- just to say VS or my code has nothing wrong.

As the exception happends during loading Excel, calling ntdll.dll, I suspect, something is wrong with the user profile caching for remote login (roaming).

But I'm not familiar with this part, any suggestion?